# Filtering views content based on currently logged in user

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I'm new to Drupal and don't really know what to look for.

I need to achieve behavior like this:

- I create content of type X
- Content of X may and will contain user names of my portal in it
- User U logs to my portal and lists all of X (using a view)
- I want to filter all X to only these, on which U is mentioned.

I don't want to use groups for this, because there will be like 100s of users and using groups and permissions will be really annoying.

**EDIT**
Available context filters:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it very nasty and ugly way. I've changed `node.tpl.php` of my theme to have `<article>` section render conditionally:

```
<?php 
    $renderContent = TRUE;
    $fieldname = 'field_fulltext_user_search';
    if (property_exists($node, $fieldname) && array_key_exists($node->language, $node->{$fieldname})) {
        $fieldValue = $node->{$fieldname}[$node->language][0]['value'];
        if (isset($fieldValue) && $fieldValue) {
            // check if content contains current user's name
            $safeBody = $body[0]['safe_value'];
            $theUser = $user->name;
            $renderContent = strpos($safeBody, $theUser)!==false;
        }
    }

    if ($renderContent):
?>
```

So now, when a node has `field_fulltext_user_search` field and its value is `true` then node content is searched for current user name. If it does not exist node is not rendered.

There're probably better solutions to this task but this worked for me fine. If you can think of better one, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the following steps:

1. In your view settings page, under "Advanced" section, click to add new "Contextual argument".
2. From the list of fields, choose the field that contains the "usernames" in your content type X.
3. From the section "When the filter value is NOT available", choose "Provide default value" and for the type, choose "User ID from logged in user".

That would be all.

Comment: Where do you reference the users inside your content type X ?!

Comment: In body/description. I write for example something like this: "Thanks for u1, u2. u3 - you rock!", and I'd like to have this node visible for users u1, u2, u3 only. It's not a reference itself, it's just a string which substring contains names of users

Comment: There is no way -as far as I know- views can do that for you, if the usernames are referenced as strings inside body field. Try to reference the users using a separate field.